# Why didn't Dumbledore bring Fawkes, along with Harry, to the Horcrux Cave?

Tags: harry-potter, horcrux, albus-dumbledore, phoenix

Since Dumbledore couldn't apparate into or out of the Horcrux Cave, wouldn't Fawkes have been a great asset to bring since his status as a phoenix means that he can nullify the effects of the Anti-Disapparition Jinx and Anti-Apparition Charm that was placed over the Horcrux cave? He wouldn't have needed to swim the entire length between the rock and the Horcrux cave?

Fawkes aided in the rather extremely powerful and flashy departure of Albus Dumbledore when the then-Minister Cornelius and his three-member vanguard attempted to arrest him and take him to Azkaban.

Dumbledore not bringing Fawkes with him seemed out of place.

Comment: We can only speculate on Albus Dumbledore motives. Maybe Fawkes was a small hatchling at the moment, after being reborn?

Comment: I got the impression Fawkes was a friend and companion more than a servant - maybe he didn't want to go to the cave?

Comment: @Michael the first part is a very good point. I do wonder why Fawkes wouldn't want to come though--he came to the Chamber to aid Harry so this seems like a somewhat similar scenario

Comment: @Michael I don't know... Dumbledore nearly died there and Fawkes was just like "nah, I don't feel like going today"? Especially as in Camber of Secrets he didn't have to go along with Harry, he was able to appear only when he was needed.

Answer (score 1):

There are whole host of things Dumbledore didn't do when going into the cave, and we can only speculate as to why. As a general answer, it simply may not have occurred to him.

Possible reasons that would apply to Fawkes:

- He may have believed that Fawkes, a highly magical creature, would have set off some kind of alarm in the cave.
- He did not know if Fawkes Apparation-like ability would work in the cave. He did not know that a house elf's magic could get around the cave's charms.
- Fawkes was asleep.

Really, we have very little to go on.

Comment: the first point you made seems reasonable

Comment: Your last point seems eminently valid.

Comment: Fawkes was definitely not asleep- we see in chapter 25 of half blood prince- "He did not knock upon Dumbledore's door, he hammered; and the calm voice answered 'Enter' after Harry had already flung himself into the room.
Fawkes the phoenix looked round, his bright black eyes gleaming with reflected gold from the sunset beyond the window. Dumbledore was standing at the window looking out at the grounds, a long, black travelling cloak in his arms."